# Upload files with ajax and existing form data

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, form-data

I'm saving a form with ajax that posts data from Vue JS.

`var data = JSON.stringify(vm.data);`

I wish to upload files in the same request. I've seen a few examples using `FormData`. However I can't seem to find an example of how to add files and still post the existing data in the same request.

I've seen that specific fields can be added using `formData.append(name, value);` but this just seems to be one value at a time. The object I'm posting is an array of objects and also contains child objects.

Is it possible to append the complete in one go, or will I have to append each item while iterating through the existing data?

EDIT - Exiting ajax request:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(vm.data);

me.xhr({
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    method: 'PUT',
    url: 'swatch/' + vm.swatch.id + '.json',
    callback: function(res) {
        vm.saving = false;
        try {
            alert(res.message ? res.message : "Swatch saved successfully");
        } catch (e) {
            alert(res.message ? res.message : "Failed to save the changes, please try again.");
        }
    },
    onerror: () => {
        vm.saving = false;
        alert('Failed to save the changes, please try again.');
    },
    data: { swatch: data }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code which you tried?

Comment: Yes you can go in one shot, why do you need to append, send JSON object directly to server

Comment: Which part would you like to see? I’ve posted how I’m currently sending the data. I’m unsure of how to combine it with files when using formData.

Comment: Part where you are using ajax to send data to server

Comment: I've added my existing code which does not include the formData yet. It calls a custom xhr method for submitting requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use FormData in:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(vm.data);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('data',data);
fd.append('file',vm.fileUploaded);

me.xhr({
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
method: 'PUT',
url: 'swatch/' + vm.swatch.id + '.json',
callback: function(res) {
    vm.saving = false;
    try {
        alert(res.message ? res.message : "Swatch saved successfully");
    } catch (e) {
        alert(res.message ? res.message : "Failed to save the changes, please try again.");
    }
},
onerror: () => {
    vm.saving = false;
    alert('Failed to save the changes, please try again.');
},
data: fd
}
```

component:

```
<input type="file" @onchange="changed($event)">


new vue({
data:{fileUploaded:''},
  methods:{
      changed(event){
           this.fileUploaded = event.target.files[0];
       }
   }
})
```